# Need the table to Overflow on the Next Row components

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

[image]

The search results are displayed in a table. I want the table to overflow on the next row component instead it expands pushing down the next row.

What css changes should I do? Following code is an extract. The table with search list pushes the next row of components down. Instead I want the table to on top of next row components

```
<div className="flex flex-wrap self-start justify-end z-2">
        <form className="md:flex flex-row flex-wrap self-start lg:ml-auto mr-8">
          <div className="relative flex flex-wrap self-start mt-4 mr-8">
            <select
              className="px-2 py-1 placeholder-blueGray-300 text-gray-300 relative bg-gray-900 rounded text-sm border border-blueGray-300 outline-none focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline w-full pr-10"
              value={tz}
              onChange={(e) => {
                settz(e.target.value);
              }}
            >
              {getTZOptions()}
            </select>
          </div>

          <div className="relative flex flex-wrap mt-4 mr-8">
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Search Project"
              className="px-2 py-1 placeholder-blueGray-300 text-gray-300 relative bg-gray-900 rounded text-sm border border-blueGray-300 outline-none focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline w-full pr-10"
              value={srchTerm}
              onChange={(e) => {
                setsrchTerm(e.target.value);
                var list = exampleSrchConsts.filter((item) => {
                  return item
                    .toLowerCase()
                    .indexOf(e.target.value.toLowerCase() > -1);
                });
                setsrchList(list);
              }}
            />
            {srchTerm.length > 0 && (
              <span
                className="h-full leading-snug font-normal absolute text-center text-blueGray-300 absolute bg-transparent rounded text-base items-center justify-center w-8 right-0 pr-2 py-1"
                onClick={() => {
                  //console.log(oldDisplayList);
                  setsrchTerm("");
                  setsrchList();
                }}
              >
                <i className="fas fa-times text-red-500"></i>
              </span>
            )}
            <table className="w:full table table-bordered bg-white ml-2">
              <tbody>{srchList}</tbody>
            </table>
          </div>

          <div className="relative flex justify-center flex-wrap self-start mt-4 mr-8 border rounded">
            <i
              className={
                "fas fa-th text-gray-700 px-2 py-2 border-r cursor-pointer"
              }
            ></i>
            <i
              className={"fas fa-table text-gray-700 px-2 py-2 cursor-pointer"}
            ></i>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).